# itimerval timer restart and stop

Tags: c++, timer

how can I stop the timer and give it a new time to expire?

how can I restart the timer after it been ended?

how can I restart the timer from the signal handler (handler_func)?

example:

```
struct sigaction real_sa;
struct itimerval real_timer;
real_sa.sa_handler = &handler_func;

if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &real_sa,NULL) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "system error: sigaction error\\n" <<
              std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
real_timer.it_value.tv_sec = (absolute_time/1000000);
real_timer.it_value.tv_usec = (absolute_time % 1000000);
if (setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &real_timer, NULL))
{
    std::cerr << "system error: setitimer error\\n" <<
              std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

thanks in advance

edit : this code  develop on linux environment and should work on linux (other platform are not important to me)

Comment: Can you please give more context, which specific framework you're using. Neither `sigaction` nor `itimerval` are standard c++ types.

Comment: I use itimerval in order to puts timer, and when the timer passed, using sigaction in order to use handler_func - meaning when the time passed the function "handle_func" would be called, I am hope I was able to clear my self, if not, I will try to explain myself again.

Comment: I suspect you're developing your code in a linux environment, but that's not clear from your question. As mentioned these types aren't supported by standard c++. Add additional tags or add some explanation where these types come from.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I stop the timer and give it a new time to expire?

By calling `setitimer` with a zeroed `it_value` (it's in the manpage).

> how can I restart the timer after it been ended?

By calling `setitimer`  again.

> how can I restart the timer from the signal handler (handler_func)?

You shouldn't. it's not a guaranteed to be async-signal-safe. You can send a message to a thread to restart it for you.

Comment: "zeroed it_value" meaning by call setitimer with stop_timer when stop_timer is:    stop_timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    stop_timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;